# Make session readonly on asp.net programmatically (EnableSessionState="ReadOnly")

Tags: asp.net

I need to make the session readonly so I can establish multiple requests to a page that uses sessions variables but in the readonly mode.

Since all the process are performed on my server control I need a way to make the session readonly programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario there must be one page who can write on session and other have no right to write on it. page that has session-state write access will hold a writer lock on the session until the request finishes. A page gains write access to the session state by setting the EnableSessionState attribute on the @Page directive to True. A page that has session-state read access for example, when the EnableSessionState attribute is set to ReadOnly, will hold a reader lock on the session until the request finishes.

```
<% @Page EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" %>
```

for more [information you can read this link](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/207800860).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, just setting that attribute on the page isn't doing it programatically. programatically means using code

Comment: EnableSessionState attribute is set to ReadOnly ***performance issues*** ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use ASP.NET MVC, you can use the `SessionStateAttribute` class on the controller level.

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

If you want to control the behavior on an action level, you can use this:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/session-state-behavior-per-action-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

If you use ASP.NET Web Forms, I am not quite sure, but it should be something along these lines...

Comment: @Kiquenet I haven't noticed anything major. I guess you just add a little overhead for checking the action attributes on each client call. I haven't measured how much delay that is. But if that is a problem you could use some sort of caching too, most likely.