# asp.net variable setted even if EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state

I've got a page that have the directive **EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"** setted.

When i have:

```
this.Session.Add("MyVar","TempVar");
```

the next request returns **NULL**.

When i have:

```
this.Session["MyVar"] = "TempVar";
```

the next request return **"TempVar"**

can i disable this behavior?

Comment: Do you want it only for this page or the whole webapp?

Comment: Just this page. I can't seam to understand why adding an item to the colection with "add" it's just temporary while setting an item it's "global"

Comment: Hope the followings links will be of great help for you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506273/make-session-readonly-on-asp-net-programmatically-enablesessionstate-readonly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506273/make-session-readonly-on-asp-net-programmatically-enablesessionstate-readonly) [http://forums.asp.net/t/1375468.aspx/1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1375468.aspx/1)

Comment: "I've got a page that have the directive EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" setted."
So i must have this line:
'<% @Page EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" %>'

My problem it's the oposite when i do 'Session["A"] = "B";' i don't want in the next request that 'Session["a"] == "B"'.
I Want that in the next request 'Session["a"] == null'.

When i write 'Session.Add("a")' the behavior it's the one i expect

Comment: In the ASP.NET forums, its mentioned that its only a memory write and values are not added to the state bag, that means you will get the original value in the second page

Comment: I know that's why this don't make any sense to me! Maybe it's becouse i'm using cassini

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it does that is because Session[""] is accessing an array using a get;set; accessor that is obviously not set to check for enablesessionstate. So basically its getting put in that array, but its not getting saved. As opposed to the .Add() function which clearly has the check in it. Its probably like that to reduce the overhead on the get;set; properties.

As someone else said you might see it on that same request, but its not getting saved to the session.

Comment: MY conclusion exactly. I can't confirm trow reflector